# DeleteOneAsync and writeConcernResult.DocumentsAffected no extension method

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api2, mongodb-.net-driver

I am migrate C# web api 2 to use mongo driver version 2 , here the the code I tried, but I have a problem with using `DocumentsAffected` *no extension method*

```
public Task<bool> RemoveRefreshToken(string refreshTokenId)
        {

            var query = Builders< RefreshToken >.Filter.Where(r => r.Id==refreshTokenId);
            var writeConcernResult = mongoContext.RefreshTokens.DeleteOneAsync(query);
            return Task.FromResult(writeConcernResult.DocumentsAffected == 1);
        }
```

Do you know what I am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DeletedCount`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_DeleteResult_DeletedCount.htm) property of the returned value of type [`Task<DeleteResult>`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_DeleteResult.htm) from [`DeleteOneAsync()`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_DeleteOneAsync.htm?_ga=1.40475621.67710916.1470056180). Use `async` too on your method headers to make use of asynchronous methods:

```
async Task<bool> RemoveRefreshToken(string refreshTokenId)
{
    var query = Builders< RefreshToken >.Filter.Where(r => r.Id==refreshTokenId);
    var writeConcernResult = await mongoContext.RefreshTokens.DeleteOneAsync(query);
    return Task.FromResult(writeConcernResult.DeletedCount == 1);
}
```